# how to run logistic regression when independent variables are binary?

Tags: python, statistics, logistic-regression

I am performing logistic regression where my dependent variable is not binary but my independent variables are binary....I got stuck, how can I use Logistic regression in such case?
If anyone could help me to resolve this query..It would be great!!!

Comment: Logistic regression is actually classification. If your dependent variable is not binary, what are you classifying?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Do you mean you have multiclass dependent variables?

Comment: It's better to ask here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/